# c integer overflow - wrap around

Tags: android

I need to find a signed int that is negtavie but as an unsinged int equal to 22 (meaning after a wrap around occurs).
the int is being inputed as string and converted with "atoi".

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: there is no such number, all negative `int` when converted to `unsigned` result in a value that is greater than `UINT_MAX/2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is to have an integer type that's 5-bit long and wraps around to negative values between 16..31.

```
struct foo_t {
    int bar: 5;
} foo;
int main(void)
{
    foo.bar = 22;
    printf("Signed: %d\n", foo.bar);
    return 0;
}
```

But bitfields are perverse anyway, so I apologise...